# Cannot resolve symbol commandBehaviours wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to commandBehaviours. Whenever I say something like the following it just complains:

> cannot resolve symbol commandBehaviours

Do I need to add any reference?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
  <Setter Property="commandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.Command"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Yes, you do need to add a `commandBehaviors` namespace declaration on the top of XAML file. Also, if `commandBehaviors` is something from another assembly, you need this assembly to be referenced from your project.

Comment: Thanks Dennis but is there an easy to bind lets say a buttons Double click event to a command in the view model. I have also done some research on InteractionTriggers . Is it easier to user events of interaction triggers than commandBehaviours